# Enable a guest user to access Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, entra-id

What I want to achieve is to give access to Azure Data Factory to a guest user. I have invited a guest user and the guest user has accepted. When navigating to https://adf.azure.com the guest user gets presented with a directory choice with only one option called "Standaardmap" translating to Default Directory or something similar, instead of the Directory I have invited him to. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to provide access at the *Resoure Group* level. Just giving access trough *Data Factory* IAM is not sufficient.